# XSLT-1.0: Change value of attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml-file:

```
$ cat data.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <outer id="0" status="FAIL" >
    <nested  status="FAIL"   >
      <inner  status="FAIL"  >
        <innermost  status="FAIL"  />
      </inner>
    </nested>
  </outer>
  <outer id="1" status="VOID">
    <nested  status="VOID"  >
      <inner  status="VOID" >
        <innermost  status="VOID" />
        <innermost  status="VOID" />
      </inner>
    </nested>
  </outer>
</root>
```

This xsl-file is supposed to change the value of the `status` attribute to `VOID` if it is `FAIL`:

```
$ cat filter.xsl 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@status = 'FAIL']">
  <!--xsl:template match="*/@status[. = 'FAIL']"-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="status">VOID</xsl:attribute>
      <!--xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW VALUE</xsl:attribute-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it does not change anything. I know I match the correct nodes because I can add a new attribute at the step where the change is supposed to happen:

```
...
<!-- This works fine -->
<xsl:attribute name="newattribute">NEW VALUE</xsl:attribute>
...
```

How can I change the value of `status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it does not change anything.

Actually, that's not true. Your code works just fine, and this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="status">VOID</xsl:attribute>
```

does create a new attribute named `status` with a value of `"VOID"`.

---

The problem is with what happens next. This instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

copies the existing attributes of the context element - and since one of these attributes is also named `status`, it overwrites the `status` attribute you have just now created.

---

You could solve this by changing the order so:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@status = 'FAIL']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="status">VOID</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but the simpler solution is to focus on the attribute:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@status[. = 'FAIL']">
    <xsl:attribute name="status">VOID</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "Adding an attribute to an element replaces any existing attribute of that element with the same expanded-name." (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)